# An error occurred in a SQL Server Service Broker/Database Mirroring transport connection endpoint

Tags: sql-server, alwayson

on one of my Always on configured server, I am seeing below error messages in the SQL logs. Does anyone have an idea what would be the issue?

An error occurred in a SQL Server Service Broker/Database Mirroring transport connection endpoint - Alert Description: An error occurred in a Service Broker/Database Mirroring transport connection endpoint, Error: 8474, State: 11. Near endpoint role: Target, far endpoint address

Answer (score 0):

1. use master
   GO
   alter endpoint endpoint_name state = stopped;
   GO
   alter endpoint endpoint_name state = started;
   GO
2. other hint

Network Security group or IT windows update was running a scan that attempted to connect using the port SQL uses for database mirroring. Since the connect request was not a valid mirroring connection, errors were generated. This explains how the error also occurred on instances with no mirrored databases.